# python QLabel with special characters

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use PyQT5 and I just want to read a file on my local drive and display it on a QLabel, but some characters is not correctly displayed :

```
self.chapText = QLabel()
self.chapText.setText(open(FILE_PATH).read())
```

"é", "ç", "à", and all other french specific characters are not correctly displayed, what I need to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to see if `open(FILE_PATH, "r", encoding="utf-8")` works. You should also open/close the file properly and forget the oneliner.

Comment: Yes it's working, thank you ! :)

Comment: Fiddling with the `encoding` parameter is the solution to 99% of the problems involving symbols and accents! :)